# Firestore not adding anything inside of signInSuccessWithAuthResult

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, callback

I'm trying to add some extra data for each user. I'm using Firestore to do this, since it's already set up and working. But I can't seem to add anything from within FirebaseUI's `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback function.

```js
var db = firebase.firestore();
var uiConfig = {
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (authResult, redirectUrl) => {
      if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
        db.collection("users").add({
          garbage: "garbage"
        })
        .then(function (docRef) {
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I have checked that the callback is in fact being executed. I have also checked that the database is connected and usable outside the callback. But when I try to use it within, I get nothing. No errors, no logs, nothing. I thought maybe this has to do with scopes, since I do not fully understand those in JavaScript yet. But I have no idea how I would fix that within a callback.

Am I doing something wrong, or should I create an issue on GitHub? (and where would I do that?)

Comment: You're not checking add() for errors.  It return a promise - what does that promise say about the result?

Comment: Like I said, nothing.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the code you added for checking for errors?  There is none in the question.

Comment: Okay, done editing!

Comment: So you're saying that you know that add() is being called (presumably, you're logging or debugging to see that happen?) but there is no response?

Comment: Yes. I can add a `console.log()` inside the function to check that the callback is being run, however when I check the database, nothing gets added. But if I place the `add()` outside of the callback, it does actually add properly.